# React Native Flatlist how to show 2 rows as a single column

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I have a flat list with 2 columns. What I want to achieve is if the item is at number 1, it should contain the height of 2 items. I am able to achieve this but the problem is that the 3rd item in the list doesn't fit its place and goes under the 1st column. But it should be under the 2nd column. Its place under the 2nd column remains empty

```js
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    if (item === 1) {
      return (
        <View
          style={{height: 200, width: 150, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 5}}>
          <Text>ABC</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View
        style={{height: 100, width: 150, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 5}}>
        <Text>ABC</Text>
      </View>
    );
};
```

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: i think this post will help you achieving what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/64814956/13180560

Comment: No that i not what i am seeking for

Comment: if you have any picture explain what you want share and i will help you

Comment: you need to put 2nd and 3rd item in the same view with flex direction column.

Comment: Good idea but flatlist only renders 1 item per iteration

Comment: change your array structure to  [ item 1, [item2, item3] ]